# Laravel live update models

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I have a site, where upon loading a series of posts get shown,
these are send to the page via an controller in the following return:

`return View::make('stream')->with($this->postStream());`

postStream is just a fetch of all my postModels (eloquent)

now when the page is loaded I would love to append all new posts made since you loaded the page without refreshing, now this will be happening with AJAX (I don't think this can be done otherwise)

so I wrote the following:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'stream',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            stream = data;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
        }
    })

    console.table(stream.posts);

;},1000 * 60); // every minute
```

this get's the right amount of posts, but I can't get the contents of my posts. the following is shown when doing a `console.table(stream.posts);`

```
+-----------+--------------+------------------+------------+
|  (index)  | timestamps   |   incrementing   |   exists   |
+-----------+--------------+------------------+------------+
|    0      |    true      |      true        |    true    |
|    1      |    true      |      true        |    true    |
|    2      |    true      |      true        |    true    |
+-----------+--------------+------------------+------------+
```

How would I be able to get those out of my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Ajax, you have to use return Response::json.

You can try

controller:

```
if (Request::ajax()) {
        return Response::json(array('id' => $id,...));
    }

return View::make('stream')->with($this->postStream());
```

view:

```
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Wow that is actually perfect what I needed, so simple but effective!